# Java - Error: no suitable method found for add(int, java.lang.String)

Tags: java, addition

I am in the middle of a homework assignment and I am stuck.  At this point in my code I think I should have a gui window that opens and allows me to type "insert text number".  At this point that information is not going anywhere but it will be going into a linkedlist once I get past this problem.  I am getting two of the same error for the lines tt.add(index, element); and I can't seem to get past it.  The error is "no suitable method found for add(int, java.lang.String)".  Code is below, please advise. To clarify - this should NOT be a method error since this is a linked list.  No method should be involved.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TopTenList extends JFrame
{
private TopTenList tt;
private JTextArea listView;
private JTextField cmdTextField;
private JTextField resultTextField;

// This is the code for the GUI Window
public TopTenList()
{
    tt = new TopTenList();
    listView = new JTextArea();
    cmdTextField = new JTextField();


    //Create panel and label for the command text field
    JPanel cmdPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    cmdPanel.add(new JLabel ("Enter New Score: "));
    cmdPanel.add(cmdTextField);
    add(cmdPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    cmdTextField.addActionListener(new CmdTextListener());

    // Set up the frame
    setTitle("Top Ten Scoreholders");  // Window Title
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Behavior on close
    pack();
    setVisible(true);  // Display the window


    // Put the textArea in the center of the frame
    add(listView);
    listView.setEditable(false);
    listView.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

// Private class that responds to the new score entered by the user
private class CmdTextListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        String cmdText = cmdTextField.getText();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(cmdText);
        String cmd = sc.next();
        if (cmd.equals("insert"))
        {
            if(sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                // add index element
                int index=sc.nextInt();
                String element = sc.next();
                tt.add(index, element);

            }
            else
            {
                // add element
                String element = sc.next();
                tt.add(element);
            }
            listView.setText(tt.toString());
            pack();
            return;
        }
    }
}


   // The main method to run the top ten list

 public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
    new TopTenList();
} 
}
```

Comment: The error tells you pretty literally what the problem is.

Comment: Well, neither your `TopTenList` class or `JFrame` which it inherits from has an `add()` method that takes those arguments so ... yes, that would be the correct error. It's also unclear what you expect that would do.

Comment: Are you trying to display some text to your window?

Comment: The text that will eventually be displayed in the window will be a list of 10 items, a line that says "Enter New Score: ", and a text box for entering a command (insert right now), text and a score.  Personally I would prefer to break these into separate text boxes for error checking but that is not the assignment.

Comment: The question states "To clarify - this should NOT be a method error since this is a linked list. No method should be involved."  There is no LinkedList in that code.  There is an import for java.util.LinkedList but I don't see that every being used.

Answer (score 1):

You never made an `add(int i, Object o)` method in either of your classes. You're treating `tt` like a List when it isn't so you would need to make the method or you could try implementing the List class.

Comment: I thought that I was implementing the List class which is why the method error has been driving me batty.  How do I implement the list?  I thought that I did that with private TopTenList tt;

Answer (score 0):

The various add() methods that your TopTenList is inheriting from JFrame, and indirectly from java.awt.Container and java.awt.Component, do not provide for adding String objects, just other Component objects.

I think maybe you instead want a javax.swing.JList with a javax.swing.DefaultListModel, as the DefaultListModel.add() method would take the parameters you want.